# Excel printing a specific number in a row subject to other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file with 3 columns and 100 thousand rows. My goal is to print the number of column A, where the number in column C is the maximum and the number in column B is higher or equal to 0.9. Like this example:

```
-----+------+-----
   A |    B |   C
-----+------+-----
   1 |  0.9 | 130
   2 |    0 | 200
   3 | 0.95 |  90
```

In this example for example it should print '1' since column 1 and 3 are higher than 0.9 but 1 is higher than 3 in column C. Anyway to do this in excel?

Comment: Is there any situation where this output wouldn't be "1"? I don't understand the question maybe. Can you share more example input?

Comment: Perhaps I should have given more details. If number 3 had 150 in column C it would print 3 for example. Or if 2 had 0.9 or higher in column B it would print number 2 since it would have 0.9 or higher in columnB and the highest number in column C. Is it clearer?

Comment: yes. That makes sense now. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data in column C is positive (or at least, that the maximum value is positive), you can use this array formula:

```
= INDEX(A:A,MATCH(LARGE(((B:B>=0.9)+0)*(C:C),1),((B:B>=0.9)+0)*(C:C),0))
```

Note this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in the formula.

Comment: Thank you so much Peter. It seems to work perfectly in the first 10 rows. I will perform additional tests tomorrow, thank you!

Comment: Everything should work because the formula considers all of the rows. Once you have completed your testing, can you kindly mark my answer as correct by placing a checkmark next to it?

Answer (score 0):

This gets pretty ugly since there is no `=MAXIFS()` formula. Instead, an array formula will do the trick:

```
=SUMIFS(A1:A3, C1:C3,MAX(IF(B1:B3>=0.9, C1:C3, 0)), B1:B3,">=.9")
```

Hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering that so Excel will interpret as an array formula.

The `Sumifs()` here isn't summing more than one value so no worries there. We are grabbing the value from `A1:A3` where `C1:C3` is equal to the `MAX()` of that column where `B1:B3` is greater than or equal to `.9`. Which solves that max() issue. And then we are then only allowing selection `A1:A3` where `B1:B3` is greater than or equal to `.9`.

It's not pretty, and it requires us to check that `>=.9` condition twice, but it does the job.

Comment: Just checked, your formula seemingly doesn't work if there are duplicate entries. For example, if `B1:B3` are `{0.9;0.9;0.8}` and `C1:C3` are `{130;130;200}`, your formula returns `3` even though the `B3` is `0.8`. Consider revising formula.

Comment: That's true, since it's using `sumifs()`. This could be converted to a straight `if()` implementation, I believe since we are already CSE'ing the thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this array formula `=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(A2:A20,MATCH(MAX(--($B$2:$B$20>=0.9)*C2:C20),--($B$2:$B$20>=0.9)*C2:C20,0),1))` in cell `D2`. Confirm it with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the array formula (means you have to click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> altogether) what I came up with:

```
=INDEX(A:C,MATCH(MAX(--(B:B>=0.9)*(C:C)),(B:B>=0.9)*(C:C),0),1)
```

Please note that I used the whole column but I will suggest to only use the ranges that are needed for faster speed.

Comment: This formula only works if there are not duplicate entries. For example if the data in `B1:B3` is `{0;0;0.9}` and the data in `C1:C3` is `{130;100;130}`, the formula returns `1` when it should return `3`.

Comment: @Peter, good eyes.  Thank you for catching that.  I have made changes to my formula.